# line smoothing algorithm in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, line, smoothing

I am doing research on line generalization, which will be applied to obtain generalized Road Network map from large scale map to small scale map. I am using two operation and two algorithms. It is done in python programming language using shapefile library, it is for vector data in 2d. 
Operation: Selection and Elimination.
For selection I am using condition like, all the roads, width more than 7 meters selected, it is connected with attribute features of the roads.
Same with elimination, like all the roads, width less than 5 meter, eliminated.
So far it was no much problem.

After selection and elimination operations applied, we will have shape file, roads which passed the condition. 
I am using two algorithms, Line simplification and line Smoothing.
For simplification of line I am using Douglas-Peucker's line simplification algorithm. it is taking vector data (coordinates) and based on tolerance removing some points. I an doing it using Python programming language. After getting simplified lines it needs some editing like line smoothing. 
Here, I am using Gaussian algorithm, however it is returning  some error, which i don't understand, as i am new in programming environment

```
import numpy

 ### This is the Gaussian data smoothing function I wrote ###  

def smoothListGaussian(list1,degree):  

     window=degree*2-1  

     weight=numpy.array([1.0]*window)
     print weight

     weightGauss=[]  

     for i in range(window):  

         i=i-degree+1  

         frac=i/float(window)  

         gauss=1/(numpy.exp((4*(frac))**2))  

         weightGauss.append(gauss)  

     print weightGauss
     weight=numpy.array(weightGauss)*weight
     print weight
     print len(list1)-window


     smoothed=[0.0]*(len(list1)-window)
     print smoothed

     for i in range(len(smoothed)):  

         smoothed[i]=sum(numpy.array(list1[i:i+window])*weight)/sum(weight)  

     return smoothed


a=[[78.03881018900006, 30.315651467000066], [78.044901609000078, 30.31512798600005], [78.04927981700007, 30.312510579000048], [78.050041244000056, 30.301755415000059], [78.072646124000073, 30.281720353000082], [78.07902308000007, 30.273344651000059]]

smoothListGaussian(a,3)
```

Any, ideas, please.
Or if there any other algorithms in python which smooths lines in vector data using coordinates of the each point in the line

Any answers appreciated!

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: For the purpose of helping you with this error, only relevant information was Gaussian smoothing. Selection, elimination were irrelevant information. Please keep the information concise. This will help others to help you. And, when you say you get error, specify what error do you get. Saying, it gives help isn't helpful enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you used the code from [here](http://www.swharden.com/blog/2008-11-17-linear-data-smoothing-in-python/). You should have paid attention that the code was for a single dimension data points not for multi-dimension data points.

I am not much aware of Gaussian smoothing algorithm but after **only** briefly going through your code, I believe following is what you are trying to do (I am not sure if it gives you the result you desire). Replace last portion of your code with the following code:

```
smoothed=[0.0,0.0]*(len(list1)-window)
print smoothed

for i in range(len(smoothed)):
    smoothing=[0.0,0.0]
    for e,w in zip(list1[i:i+window],weight):
        smoothing=smoothing+numpy.multiply(e,w)
    smoothed[i]=smoothing/sum(weight)
```

Comment: But when I replace the codeit is giving some error: [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
[0.077304740443299699, 0.52729242404304844, 1.0, 0.52729242404304844, 0.077304740443299699]
[ 0.07730474  0.52729242  1.          0.52729242  0.07730474]
1
[0.0, 0.0]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/go_smo.py", line 44, in <module>
    smoothListGaussian(a,3)
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/go_smo.py", line 34, in smoothListGaussian
    smoothing[0.0,0.0]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'smoothing' referenced before assignment

Comment: @peter Works fine when I run. Are you sure, you are using right indentation and everything?

Comment: yeah, it is working, I have made a mistake, sorry for that, and Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

You can smooth the path by following code:

```
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[78.03881018900006, 30.315651467000066],
 [78.044901609000078, 30.31512798600005], 
 [78.04927981700007, 30.312510579000048],
 [78.050041244000056, 30.301755415000059],
 [78.072646124000073, 30.281720353000082],
 [78.07902308000007, 30.273344651000059]])

x, y = a.T
t = np.linspace(0, 1, len(x))
t2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

x2 = np.interp(t2, t, x)
y2 = np.interp(t2, t, y)
sigma = 10
x3 = gaussian_filter1d(x2, sigma)
y3 = gaussian_filter1d(y2, sigma)

x4 = np.interp(t, t2, x3)
y4 = np.interp(t, t2, y3)

plot(x, y, "o-", lw=2)
plot(x3, y3, "r", lw=2)
plot(x4, y4, "o", lw=2)
```

Here is the resut: blue dots are the original data, red curve are the smoothed curve which contains many points, if you want the same point count as original data, you can sample from the red curve and get the green points.

You can set `sigma` to change the smooth level of `gaussian_filter1d()`.

[image]